# How to capture a damped sine wave with an oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, voltage-measurement, resonator

Basically what I'm doing is feeding a resonator with a sine wave at roughly 1 MHz coming from a signal generator for a certain time T. After that, I'm switching off the signal generator and what I want to do is record the transient response of the resonator as it discharges, which should be a damped sine wave.
I've at my disposal a Keysight DSOX6004A oscilloscope but I'm not sure how to do this. I think I need to exploit the trigger system in some way, but I know a level triggering won't work as my resonator is going to oscillate for a time before I turn off the supply.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you trigger on this event: “I'm switching off the signal generator”?

Comment: what @whinny asks. Also, what are the time scales and bandwidths we're talking about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm switching off the SG manually so T will be in the order of a couple seconds. The frequency is around 1 MHz. I'm not sure how to trigger the scope on the turn off of the SG though

Comment: @winny aaaah sorry! No, no Freudian slip :)

Comment: @Nicol no I meant what the duration you want to record is.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it should be a few periods of the waveform, so a couple microseconds or more

Comment: So, you say you turn off the signal generator by hand; what does that mean? I mean, you don't just push the power-off button, as that would lead to undefined turn-off behaviour, and also happen at a totally random phase of the generated wave, right?